# Repair Windows ISO files

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have a old WinXP ISO file that I want to use on an old computer.

However, upon booting from the image (via USB thumb drive) the WinXP claims that some files are either corrupt or not found.

Namely: shell32.dll, and others. Just a few.

Is there a way to repair the ISO, by replacing the problem files?

After "expanding" the ISO image to a local hard disc, I could browse to the files in question, but they are in what I assume is some kind of compressed format: shell32.dl_, etc.

I have another machine that I put this particular ISO installation on (years ago) and I found and copied shell32.dll, and others in hopes of somehow "replacing" the *.dl_ files on the bad ISO image.

Is there a way to properly "compress" (I assume), the good files from *.dll to *.dl_, etc. and then replace the bad files in the ISO?

The files in question are on the ISO image in the ..\I386 folder.

Comment: The are compressed as single cab files.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than trying to patch a corrupted ISO file, I would suggest to
download it again.

You may download
[Windows XP Professional SP3 x86](https://archive.org/details/WinXPProSP3x86)
from the Wayback Archive.
This is the original file from Microsoft.

Comment: I'd suggest not letting it anywhere near a network connection: apart from the vulnerability aspect there's too much risk that you'll hit the wrong button and allow MS to kill half of it (I think I saw a recent hack that disabled the initial "phone home").